# Which tools can reproject ASCII grids?

Tags: coordinate-system, software-recommendations, esri-ascii-raster

I need to reproject my ASCII Grid data. My data format is EPSG:32629 and I need to reproject this data to WG64 format.

Someone knows any reprojection tool?

Comment: Do you have any preferred software in which you would like to achieve this, or is anything fine?

Answer (score 7):

My go-to tool for raster reprojection is [`gdalwarp`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html), since gdal supports a [myriad of formats](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/index.html) including [ASCII grid format](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/aaigrid.html).

For the task at hand (warping a `*.asc` dataset from EPSG:32629 to other CRS) I would open up a text console and run something like:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs epsg:32629 -t_srs epsg:4326 raster.asc warped.geotiff
```

Comment: Is it necessary to install some software to execute that command? I execute that command in Windows cmd  and  the console said that  gdalwarp was not recognized like a internal or external command, program or archive

Comment: Pal, do a bit of research yourself. There are links to a [download page](https://gdal.org/download.html) from all the reference webpages I mentioned in the answer.